# Windows CE Form Size Properties Not Updating After Maximize

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-ce, .net-cf-3.5

I am developing a full screen Windows CE application in C#. Once I set the WindowState to Maximized the Height and Width properties of the form remain unchanged as does the ClientRectangle and ClientSize property. The properties will not update until after the form has loaded. I need to know the values for the maximized form when it loads so that I can reposition and resize controls on it.

How can I get these values to update?

Comment: Have you tried using OnResize event handler?